# Natural Language to MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, nlp

I'm working on a mongodb query builder. I searching for a nlp library that converts to mongodb query. I found few nlp libraries that convert nlp to database query and can't foud one that convert natural language to mongo. Theres any library that fo that? The library can be on any language (.net, node, python).

I'm working on a mongodb query builder. I'm looking for a natural language library that converts to mongodb query. I have found some nlp libraries that convert natural language to database query but I have not found any that convert natural language to mongo. Is there a library for this? The library can be in any language (.net, node, python, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Spacy is a good library for feature extraction.
In entity ruler you can set rules for conditions, features and then simply extrcat those features from simple text.
Then generate Mongo queries using pymongo using rule based approach